# OPC Client - how to read from Remote OPC Server

Tags: .net, opc

I used [OPCDotNetLib](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=1135) but can't read data from remote OPC Server there .

I can connect , like

```
Type typeofOPCserver = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(clsidOPCserver, ip);
```

But looking the methods DataChanged or ReadCompleted doesn't work or works wrong.

I tested same with local OPC Server and it works well , with remote OPC Server I can connect, I can add items and can read data. OPC Server on remote machine shows that I read them, but I can't see any data. Seems like I need another workaround on OPCDotNetLib for remote OPC Server.

I even found a comment there

> This library / dll will not work on a remote server, only local use is possible.

Is there some another available OPC Client .NET Libraries ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got a few options for OPC compatibility. You can use the classical COM wrappers provided by OPC Foundation, or you can use the newer OPC library designed for .Net.

I haven't personally switched over to the newer library yet, but this is a break down of how to use `OpcNetApi.dll`,`OpcNetApi.Com.dll`, and `OpcRcw.Da.dll` to initialize a connection and subscribe to the `DataChanged` event:

```
Opc.Da.Server scadaServer = null;
List<Opc.Da.Item> scadaItems = null;
Opc.Da.Subscription scadaSubscription = null;

string scadaUrl = string.Format("opcda://{0}/{1}", hostname,
                                                   opcServerVendor);

scadaServer = new Opc.Da.Server(new OpcCom.Factory(), new Opc.URL(scadaUrl));
scadaServer.Connect();

var scadaItems = new List<Opc.Da.Item>(); // I'm using a List<T>, but cast back to a simple array using ToArray();

// Repeat this next part for all the items you need to subscribe
Opc.Da.Item item = new Opc.Da.Item();
item.ItemName = TagPath; // Where TagPath is something like device.channel.tag001;
item.ClientHandle = handle; // handle is up to you, but i use a logical name for it
item.Active = true;
item.ActiveSpecified = true;

scadaItems.Add(item);

Opc.Da.SubscriptionState subscriptionState = new Opc.Da.SubscriptionState();
subscriptionState.Active = true;
subscriptionState.UpdateRate = 40;
subscriptionState.Deadband = 0;

scadaSubscription = scadaSubscription ?? (Opc.Da.Subscription)scadaServer.CreateSubscription(subscriptionState);

Opc.Da.ItemResult[] result = scadaSubscription.AddItems(scadaItems.ToArray());
for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    scadaItems[i].ServerHandle = result[i].ServerHandle;

scadaSubscription.DataChanged += new Opc.Da.DataChangedEventHandler(OnDataChange);
scadaSubscription.State.Active = true;
```

Comment: So but where can I get OpcNetApi.dll,OpcNetApi.Com.dll, and OpcRcw.Da.dll ? :( I am not paid member of the OPC
Foundation.

Comment: @nCdy you'll need the `OPC Redistributable 2.00` from a reputable source. Otherwise you can purchase a fleshed out component from a company like Kepware or Matrikon.

Comment: @GregBuehler I am disconnecting but the client remains active on the opc server side. Do you know why?

Answer (score 4):

I know it has been a while but to help those who need the libraries.
To go along with Greg Buehlers answer.
They are Free and part of the core OPC Foundation and can be found [here](https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/developer-kits-classic/core-components/) click on Archives tab if you need previous versions.  It took me forever to find them so I hope this may help someone.

Comment: The link seems to be dead. I assume it's moved here https://opcfoundation.org/developer-tools/samples-and-tools-classic/core-components/. Requires registration though.