# Connecting to OPC server with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, opc

I’m trying to use PowerShell to read values from an OPC server. I have been doing some research but I can’t see any reference or similar case.

I installed the Matrikon OPC Simulation server and tried loading OPCdotNETLib.dll assembly. The assembly is loaded successfully. I can see intellisense when operating with the objects. I’m not getting any error now but I don’t think is connecting successfully.

```
$Path = "C:\OPCdotNETLib.dll"
Add-Type -Path $Path
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Runtime.InteropServices') 

$OPCServer = New-Object OPC.Data.OpcServer
$OPCServer = [OPC.Data.OPCServer]::new()
$OPCServerName = "Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1"
$OPCServer.Connect($OPCServerName)
```

Would you have any clue or help reference?

Comment: [Maybe related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4926296/1630171).

Answer (score 1):

You can use QuickOPC (http://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc ; disclaimer: this is a self-promotion). OPC read is done as follows:

```
Add-Type -Path OpcLabs.EasyOpcClassic.dll

# Create EasyOPC-DA component 
$client = New-Object OpcLabs.EasyOpc.DataAccess.EasyDAClient

# Read item value and display it
$client.ReadItemValue("", "OPCLabs.KitServer.2", "Demo.Single")
```

Taken from: http://kb.quickopc.com/How_to_read_an_OPC_item_value_in_PowerShell

Comment: Thanks for your help, ZbynekZ

I gave it a try. It Works. However, the QuickOPC dll that come with the free trial only allows connections of less than 30 minutes.

Would you know any free dll for OPC that I can use? Perhaps from OPC Fundation?

Thanks

Comment: Basically all the stuff from OPC Foundation is now open-sourced, and free for use as long as your own project is kept open-source. To my knowledge, however, it would be much more difficult to make it work under PowerShell. But I have not tried.

Comment: Thanks, Zbynek, I agree, I've tried and I think it's easier with QuickOPC dll. Would you know how to subscribe for item changes? I am trying to read from just one tag in advise/event-based mode. I saw some examples with php and csharp, but nothing with Powershell.

Comment: I have put it quickly together (I am not a PowerShell guy at all). Use Register-ObjectEvent and hook some code to the "ItemChanged" event, and then call EasyDAClient.SubscribeItem. It is now here: http://kb.quickopc.com/How_to_subscribe_to_OPC_data_changes_in_PowerShell .